# Efficient update with join

Tags: sql-server, update

I have a table with ~10,000 rows that looks like:

```
main (
    external_id varchar,
    int_col     int,
    varchar_col varchar,
    date_col    datetime2,
    text_col    text,
    -- and 50 other columns
)
```

Then there is a script which creates a temporary table containing ~2,000 rows:

```
temp (
    external_id varchar,
    int_col     int,
    varchar_col varchar,
    date_col    datetime2,
    text_col    text
)
```

I insert the data into main table from temp table using this query:

```
insert into main(...)
select ... from temp
where not exists (select 1 from main where main.external_id = temp.external_id)
```

This inserts rows that do not already exist. The next step is to update existing data in main table from temp table. I use the following query which does not look efficient:

```
update main set
main.int_col     = temp.int_col,
main.varchar_col = temp.varchar_col,
main.date_col    = temp.date_col,
main.text_col    = temp.text_col
from main
inner join temp on main.external_id = temp.external_id
```

It will always overwrite 4 columns of 2,000 rows. In practice only 5-10 rows and only 1-2 columns will be different. Is there an efficient method to update the data?

I have tried the following but it does not work for `text` datatype:

```
where checksum() <> checksum()
```

The other solution is to compare each column three ways but results in a very long query and still has trouble with `text` datatype:

```
where main.int_col <>              temp.int_col
or    main.int_col is     null and temp.int_col is not null
or    main.int_col is not null and temp.int_col is     null
```

So again, is it possible to make it efficient, update only those rows that need to be changed?

Comment: "It will always overwrite 4 columns of 2,000 rows" -- why is that a problem? Have you tried doing the `update` _before_ you `insert` new rows?

Comment: Since `text` is [a deprecated datatype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), and seems to be at the root of a couple of your problems, why not convert to a more modern, supported data type?

Comment: _but results in a very long query_ Your desire to avoid just a little bit of work should not be a factor or concern in writing efficient and correct SQL.

Comment: @mus I don't understand how that helps. Next time the script runs there will be ~2010 rows in the set, 10 need to be inserted, other 2,000 already exist in db and very small percentage of them contain a minor change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data sent to the script by the third party contains a `modified_date` column. I have decided to store this column in my database and update only those rows where this date is different:

```
update main set
main.int_col       = temp.int_col,
main.varchar_col   = temp.varchar_col,
main.date_col      = temp.date_col,
main.text_col      = temp.text_col
main.modified_date = temp.modified_date
from main
inner join temp on main.external_id = temp.external_id
where main.modified_date is null or main.modified_date <> temp.modified_date
```